# Aggregating and projecting soilgrids rasters giving NaNs using R

Tags: r, soilgrids

Working with the latest soilgrids data, I'm finding that when I aggregate and project the rasters as follows:

```
soil_ocs = terra::rast('ocs_0-30cm_mean_5000.tif')
aggregated <- terra::aggregate(soil_ocs,fact=4, na.rm=TRUE)
projected = terra::project(aggregated, "epsg:4326")
```

The aggregated maps look fine (see below).

But when I extract values for a set of points e.g. with

```
var_values = data.frame(extract(projected, f[, c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude")], factors=FALSE))
```

where `df` is some dataframe, there are lots of NaN values and I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong or if I can improve the coverage of the data somehow.

[image]

Comment: Why are you changing the raster CRS to the geographic domain? Do you need to compute distances? The [method below by Robert Hijmans](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431471/21532) would be the logical way to obtain the result you seek. In any case, with the WGS:84 datum ensemble the xx coordinate is latitude and the yy coordinate is longitude. At least that appears incorrect in your code snippet.

Comment: It seemed easier on resources to reproject the raster then extract the values rather than reprojecting the points and then extracting the values as I'm working with ~3million instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if a lot of NANs are returned by this:

```
e <- extract(projected, df[, dc("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude")]
```

That suggest that you have a lot of points that are not on land.

Either way, what you are doing is wrong. You should never project raster data unless you absolutely have to (for example to match different raster data sets). You should project the points instead.

```
soil_ocs = terra::rast('ocs_0-30cm_mean_5000.tif')
v <- vect(df[, dc("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"), crs="+proj=longlat")
v <- project(v, crs(soil_ocs))
e <- extract(soil_ocs, v)
```

Or after some aggregation as in your example

```
agg <- aggregate(soil_ocs, fact=4, na.rm=TRUE)
e <- extract(agg, v)
```

Comment: Great thanks for this. This is computationally quite expensive as I'm working with lots of instances so the vector projection uses up a lot of RAM, but anyway I've implemented your suggestions. I'm not sure that there are less NaNs now, but on inspection I can see that the NaNs are coming from coordinates that aren't on land, or are very close to oceans/lakes.

Comment: Typically it would be more expensive the way you did it (large raster, few points); but, either way, this is the *correct* way of doing it, and that should matter most.

Comment: This method is only more expensive if there are more points to project than cells in the raster.